# What does this BusyBox initramfs error message mean?

Tags: initramfs, busybox

I re-installed Ubuntu, but after a couple of days I got the BusyBox error again.

[image: Error message]

Comment: It shows several I/O errors in the drive. That means it's defective and needs to be replaced.

Answer (score 2):

**initramfs**, abbreviated from "initial RAM file system", is a cpio ("copy in and out") archive of the initial file system that gets loaded into memory during the Linux startup process.It is used as the first root file system that your machine has access to.

**BusyBox** is software that provides several stripped-down Unix tools in a single executable file. It provides replacements for most of the utilities you usually find in GNU fileutils, shellutils, etc.

You get the Busybox initramfs error when your file system partition has some errors. In the output they tell you the partition which is corrupted.

When you encounter this type of problem, you need to check and repair the problematic Linux filesystems with the `fsck` command.

Suppose you have the following error message:

```
**/dev/sda1** contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Inode 4326476 extent tree (at level 1) could be narrower, IGNORED.
/dev/sda1: Inode 4326843 extent tree (at level 1) could be narrower,IGNORED.
/dev/sda1: Inode 4327012 extent tree (at level 1) could be narrower,IGNORED.
/dev/sda1: Inode 4329004 extent tree (at level 1) could be narrower,IGNORED.
/dev/sda1: Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.


/dev/sda1: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
(i.e., without -a or -p options) 
fsck exited with status code 4. 
**The root filesystem on /dev/sda1 requires a manual fsck.** 


BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4ubuntu6.1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

In this case you see that the corrupted partition is `/dev/sda1`. To solve the problem, we will use the `fsck` command specifying the partition which is corrupted (`/dev/sda1`):

```
fsck /dev/sda1 -y
```

After the execution is done, run:

```
exit
```

Please note that sometimes you don't see any errors after running the `exit` command. In that case, try to run `fsck` on all filesystems.

Answer (score 0):

Select advanced Ubuntu from the boot menu. Select the non-recovery option, then upgrade packages.
This will take time, maybe hours but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Im not a tech expert but this problem happened to me after set bios to default and then i understood that this happend because of the change happened in SATA mode

I finally changed it back and now its working.
So check your SATA mode in bios if its changed.